# Setting GLOG_minloglevel=1 to prevent output in shell from Caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, glog

I'm using Caffe, which is printing a lot of output to the shell when loading the neural net.
I'd like to suppress that output, which supposedly can be done by setting `GLOG_minloglevel=1` when running the Python script. I've tried doing that using the following code, but I still get all the output from loading the net. How do I suppress the output correctly?

```
os.environ["GLOG_minloglevel"] = "1"
net = caffe.Net(model_file, pretrained, caffe.TEST)
os.environ["GLOG_minloglevel"] = "0"
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To supress the output level you need to **increase** the loglevel to at least 2

```
 os.environ['GLOG_minloglevel'] = '2'
```

The levels are

0 - debug
 1 - info (still a LOT of outputs)
 2 - warnings
 3 - errors

---

**Update:**
Since this flag is *global* to `caffe`, it must be set *prior* to importing of `caffe` package (as pointed out by [jbum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350273/1714410)). Once the flag is set and `caffe` is imported the behavior of the GLOG tool cannot be changed.

Comment: > `minloglevel` Log messages at or above this level. Again, the numbers of severity levels INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL are 0, 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html

Comment: In case of PyCharm, You can set environment variable as follows:

1)  Click  menu item `Run`  - `Edit Configurations...`
2)  Find `Environment variables:` in the `Environment` group in `Configuration` tab and click the rightmost `...` icon

3) Click `+` and set Name `GLOG_minloglevel` and its value `2` or you want.

You don't need to use ` os.environ['GLOG_minloglevel'] = '2' ` before `import caffe` and don't need to restart PyCharm session.

Answer (score 28):

I was able to get [Shai's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788785/1714410) to work, but only by executing that line in Python *before* calling

```
import caffe
```