# Disable and renable logging created from C++ module in Python

Tags: python, c++, logging, caffe

I'm using a deep learning library, Caffe, which is written in C++ and has an interface to Python. One of my commands creates a lot of unnecessary output to the log and I would really like to remove that by temporarily disabling logging.

Caffe uses GLOG and I've tried using`os.environ["GLOG_minloglevel"] = "2"` to only log important messages. However, that didn't work. I've also tried using the Python logging module to shut down all logging temporarily using the code below, which didn't work either.

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.disabled = True    
net = caffe.Net(model_file, pretrained, caffe.TEST)
root_logger.disabled = False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting GLOG\_minloglevel=1 to prevent output in shell from Caffe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788075/setting-glog-minloglevel-1-to-prevent-output-in-shell-from-caffe)

Answer (score 2):

`GLOG_minloglevel=3` ,only by executing that line in Python before calling

so,you can try

```
os.environ["GLOG_minloglevel"] ="3"
import caffe
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set the log level environmental variable before you start Python. Or at leastt this worked for me:

GLOG_minloglevel=3 python script.py

Which silenced loading messages.

Comment: Yes, but how do I reenable them for other messages?

Comment: Change the log level for your desired output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788075/setting-glog-minloglevel-1-to-prevent-output-in-shell-from-caffe