# Caffe prints entire protext file on net_.reset(new Net<float>(model_file, TEST))

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, caffe

I am using on Caffe C++ for a Deep learning application. Whenever I load the model file, it prints the contents of entire .protext file on to the console. 
The printing is happening at this point,

```
shared_ptr<Net<float> > net_;
net_.reset(new Net<float>(model_file, TEST));
```

How do I disable this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the verbosity (i.e., how much caffe prints to the log) of caffe using the environment variable `GLOG_minloglevel`. By default, caffe outputs all log messages of level "info" (1) and up.  Try setting it to 2 (warnings) to disable most of the printouts.

```
~$ GLOGminloglevel=2 my_app_that_uses_caffe
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788785/1714410) for more information.