# How do I get Caffe failure stack trace to display?

Tags: python, c++, caffe, pycaffe

Debugging a Python script which is calling pycaffe which in turn is calling Google protobuf.

When I run the script I get the error:

```
F0304 10:19:58.538651 18829 io.cpp:67] Check failed: proto.SerializeToOstream(&output) 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

But no failure stack trace.  How do I get the stack trace to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the value of your environment variable [`GLOG_minloglevel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788785/1714410)

```
export GLOG_minloglevel=2
```

before running caffe.